# Obtener valor de una cadena después de un guion ORACLE

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

como puedo obtener de una cadena lo que esta despues de un guion (-) en oracle, solo tengo la instruccion donde se establece cierto indice y que de ahi me tome mi cadena pero no siempre es el mismo valor ya que la cadena puede variar su tamaño y quiero obtener mejor lo que este despues de un guion

> CADENA =>   ImD: 448 - TEST DE RUTA18122019

mi instrucción:

```
SUBSTR(CADENA,11)
```

Comment: Podrias intentar ocupar regexp_subst, te dejo una respuesta en Stackoverflow en Inglés https://stackoverflow.com/a/28677633/11335797 y luego ocupar el valor según la fila, es decir, separas la query en 2 partes, antes y después del guión y luego ocupas el valor que necesites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola primero puedes obtener la posicion de esta manera

```
INSTR(CADENA,'-')
```

Lo cual devuelve un numero entero, al final quedaria asi.

```
SUBSTR(CADENA,(INSTR(CADENA,'-') +1))
```

Comment: Justo lo que queria gracias